# Deploy Axis2 webservice on older Axis

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

i have deployed a web service on Axis2 .. the generated interface is .aar filem i am trying to deploy it on an older axis version that takes .wsdd files .. how can i do that ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis and Axis2 services are not compatible.

You will have to take your classes that you wrote for your Axis2 service, put them into an Axis project, and write the appropriate .wsdd file, and perform any other necessary code or configuration changes.

:(

Comment: thanks alot :) and i guess also the client code will have to change also rit ?

Comment: um not necessarily...in theory you may be able to get the two services to produce the same wsdl.